# Same docker-compose.yml, but now working on Windows

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am new to docker, and I am trying to run my Svelte project with docker.
This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - '.:/usr/src/app'
      - 'node_modules:/usr/src/app/node_modules'

volumes:
  node_modules:
```

And `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:14-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

This goes well on my Macbook, but it is not working on my Windows desktop. What is the reason?
And I solved this problem with fixing `docker-compose.yml` like this:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - '.:/usr/src/app'
      - '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
```

What is the difference between this code and previos `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: Well,  the second compose creates a named volume with a random name, that'll be  gone the  next time you restart the container. The first one uses a named volume that'll still be there  through container restarts `node_modules`. That change to me doesn't seem like a reason for it to work in both suddenly.  Are you using WSL in windows? If not, it might be  having a problem with npm not existing on the windows system.

Comment: Could you post the error message of running it on windows?

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. The problem was not caused by the OS difference, it is because of named volume. When I tested on Windows, I created docker container with old package.json first, so an error occurs when I created another container with updated package.json, because the named volume wasn't changed and the updated package was not installed to the volume.